# Why is the value of the reference before the null assignment returned to the calling method?

Tags: java

I am unable to determine why the sb object reference value that gets mirrored back to the calling method does not mirror the last value (i.e. null) that it was assigned?

```
  public class Test{
   void testRefs(String str, StringBuilder sb){
    str = str + sb.toString();
    sb.append(str);
    System.out.println(sb);
    str = null;
    sb = null;
    System.out.println(sb);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "aaa";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("bbb");
    new Test().testRefs(s, sb);
    System.out.println("s="+s+" sb="+sb);
  }
}
```

Comment: Read, no study, this duplicate: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value). It will explain all.

Comment: Because Java is always pass-by-value always, you can change the *state* of a reference parameter within the method but you can't change the ***reference*** itself which is what you're trying to do.